# Why does my method for computing roots with multiplicity give the wrong answer at infinity, and can it be repaired?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, projective-space, meromorphic-functions

To solve equations in a way that tells you not just the solutions, but the multiplicities, I had the following idea:

- Use the metaphor of "integer-valued logic." Replace "and" with multiplication and "or" with addition.
- Replace $=$ with some other symbol like $\#$ to mean that the result is integer valued, as opposed to boolean valued. For instance, whereas the equation $(x-1)^5 = 0$ has value False for $x \neq 1$ and True for $x=1$, the expression $(x-1)^5 \,\#\, 0$ has value $0$ for $x \neq 1$ and $5$ for $x=1$.

For example, the null-factor law reads $$(ab \,\#\, 0) = (a \,\#\, 0)+(b\,\#\,0)$$

This seems to work pretty well in the affine plane. For example, suppose we to study the example on p.28 of Silverman's "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves." In particular, we wish to find the zeroes of $$x-a$$ on the curve $$y^2 = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c).$$ We compute:

$(x-a\,\#\,0) \cdot (y^2 \,\#\, (x-a)(x-b)(x-c))$

$=(x\,\#\,a) \cdot (y^2 \,\#\, (x-a)(x-b)(x-c))$

$=(x\,\#\,a) \cdot (y^2 \,\#\, (a-a)(a-b)(a-c))$

$=(x\,\#\,a) \cdot (y^2 \,\#\, 0)$

$=(x\,\#\,a) \cdot 2(y \,\#\, 0)$

$=2(x\,\#\,a)(y \,\#\, 0)$

Ergo $x-a$ has exactly one zero on the curve of interest, it occurs at $x=a,y=0$, and it has multiplicity $2$. This agrees with Silverman's answer, so it seems to work.

However, according to Silverman, $x-a$ also has a zero on the  "at infinity" with multiplicity $-2$. To find it, the obvious thing to do is to homogenize everything in sight and do the same computation again. In particular:

$(x-az\,\#\,0) \cdot (y^2z \,\#\, (x-az)(x-bz)(x-cz))$

$=(x\,\#\,az) \cdot (y^2z \,\#\, 0)$

$=(x\,\#\,az) \cdot (2(y \,\#\, 0)+(z\,\#\,0))$

$=2(x\,\#\,az)(y \,\#\, 0)+(x\,\#\,az)(z \,\#\, 0)$

$=2(x\,\#\,az)(y \,\#\, 0)+(x\,\#\,0)(z \,\#\, 0)$

We surmise that there's a root at $(a:0:1)$ with multiplicity $2$ and and another at $(0:1:0)$ with multiplicity $1$. But this contradicts Silverman's answer, which is that the point at infinity has multiplicity $-2$.

> **Question.** Why does my method for computing roots with multiplicity give the wrong answer at infinity, and can it be repaired?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but in an affine open neighborhood of $[0:1:0]$ we can write the curve as $v = (u - av)(u - bv)(u - cv)$ and the function $x - a$ becomes $\frac{u}{v} - a$, where $u = X/Y$ and $v = Z/Y$ in terms of the homogeneous coordinates.  Does your method give the right answer for this affine curve?

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem now: "homogenize everything in sight" is actually not the right thing to do.  We consider the closure an affine curve $C: f(x,y) = 0$ in projective space (with homogeneous coordinates $X,Y,Z$), by saying that we've been working in the affine open set where $Z \neq 0$ with affine coordinates $x = X/Z$ and $y = Y/Z$.  In terms of the homogeneous coordinates, the function $x - a$ is $\frac{X}{Z} - a$.  By "homogenizing" the function $x - a$, you changed it: $X - aZ$ vs. $\frac{X}{Z} - a$.

Comment: I guess what you're actually computing is the intersection multiplicities of the points of intersection of the curves $X - aZ = 0$ and $Y^2 Z = (X - aZ)(X - bZ)(X - cZ)$, which certainly should add up to $3$ by Bézout's Theorem.  But this is different from considering the function $x - a$ on the curve, as I mentioned above.

Comment: @Quasicoherent, okay, that kind of makes sense. I'll try to get the computations to work with those comments in mind when I have a bit more time. Thanks for your input :)